# How to display console tab of intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

If I use "find usage" to look for usage of some methods or fields, intellij will hide the console tab and take me to another tab. How can I switch back to the console tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to use Ctrl-Tab (Switcher) which shows the list of all toolwindows along with the list of open files. Another is to press the button in the bottom left corner of the IntelliJ IDEA toolwindow to show the toolwindow tabs. You can also switch to the toolwindow directly by pressing Alt-4 (for Run) or Alt-5 (for Debug).

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the "Debug" view and accidentally close the console output, you can select "Restore Layout". Control Shift-A to bring Help Command, type "Restore Layout", and it should restore the console tab.

There are also two icons in the Debug window that can do that if you have the Debug Toolbar active. On the left side, a 3 rectangle icon is "Restore Layout". On the top right of the Debug panel is a"Console" icon that will restore just the console.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "console", do you mean terminal? ALT+F12 (for Windows) will open the terminal window, if it is not open. If the terminal *is* open, but is not the active window, ALT+F12 will make it active. If the terminal is open and is active, ALT+F12 will close it.

Answer (score 0):

Note if the console output is output from application server such as Tomcat, Alt-5 does not necessarily have to work even if application has been started in debug mode. Console tab is (together with Debugger tab) opened on application server start as part of Services window, hence Alt-8 is the right shortcut to access it.